# Namespace error when using gridview using custom theme in yii2

Tags: php, gridview, namespaces, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I am new to yii2, but I have been using Yii 1.x for quite a long time. I am using advanced template of Yii2 and implementing custom theme for the backend. I am using https://github.com/mithun12000/adminUI theme for the backend. I have set up my theme as follows:

1. install theme using composer
2. added theme support in backend/config/main.php as follows:

   ```
   'view'=>[
       'theme'=>[
           'pathMap'=>['@app/views'=>'@webroot/themes/admin/views'],
           'baseUrl'=>'@web/themes/admin'
       ]
   ],
   ```
3. Changed namespace app\assets; into namespace backend\assets; in backend/assets/AppAsset.php
4. I created my theme in web folder as backend/web/themes/admin and put my views there.
5. In my controller, to use the theme I just created, I put the following code:

   ```
   $this->getView()->theme = Yii::createObject([
       'class' => '\yii\base\Theme',
       'pathMap' => ['@backend/views' => '@webroot/themes/admin/views'],
       'baseUrl' => '@web/themes/admin',
   ]);
   ```
6. The login screen works fine. But if I have any widget, suppose Gridview, then I get namespace error. The error I get is:

   ```
   Unknown Class – yii\base\UnknownClassException

   Unable to find 'app\assets\AppAsset' in file: D:\projects\bmjobs\site\backend/assets/AppAsset.php. Namespace missing?
   ```

If I change the namespace in AppAsset.php to app\assets, then I get the following error:

```
    PHP Fatal Error – yii\base\ErrorException

    Call to a member function checkAccess() on a non-object
```

I am not sure where I went wrong. Can anybody please help me out with this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you may change your `pathMap` in `backend/config/main.php`

```
'pathMap' => ['@app/views' => '@app/themes/admin/views'],
```

Comment: Tried it but didn't work. I still get the same error